# Get The High Of X Position Candle

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the high of x position candle based on some condition. The below is my code. But I am getting the error "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function". Is there any way to achieve that ?

```
i = 0
if(condition1)
    i := 7
else if(condition2)
    i := 8
else if(condition2)
    i := 9
x = security(syminfo.tickerid,'60',high[i])
plot(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use non-mutable variable, for example:

```
i = condition1 ? 7 : condition2 ? 8 : condition3 ? 9 : 0
h = high[i]
x = security(syminfo.tickerid,'60',high[i])
plot(x)
```